# How to display File Browser Dialog path directory on a textbox in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, textbox, directory

Im trying to select a file using the File Browser dialog and displaying the path on a textbox

for an example "C:\Program Files"

Here is an example of my code:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bwrBtn.Click

    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        rootTxt.Clear()
        Dim grade As New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
        Dim inFiles As IO.FileInfo() = grade.GetFiles()
        Dim fLinfo As IO.FileInfo
        For Each fLinfo In inFiles
            rootTxt.Text(fLinfo)
        Next

    End If
    'Exit File Directory

End Sub
```

When the user chooses a file the file directory should appear on the textbox

Comment: You did not describe a problem or ask a question, but your loop is replacing the previous result on each iteration.

Comment: My Apologies just finished editing the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a VB dev, but possibly something like this should work:

```
If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    rootTxt.Clear()
    Dim grade As New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
    Dim inFiles As IO.FileInfo() = grade.GetFiles()
    Dim fLinfo As IO.FileInfo

    Dim directoryPath As string = Path.GetDirectoryName(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)

    rootTxt.Text = directoryPath
End If
```

Comment: Please mark as answered if it answered your question

Comment: Had to wait a few minutes until it will allow me but I defiantly will when time is up